# Libgdx - Support for OpenGL 4+

Tags: opengl, libgdx

Is it possible to use Libgdx for a desktop development only and access newer versions of Opengl from Libgdx abstraction? I mean, if you want to develop mobile apps you will have to use a some verison of Opengl ES, which does not support lot of things like classic Opengl does (e.g. drawing wireframes, etc.).
Lets say I don't want to use Opengl ES but normal Opengl, version 4+ in these days, and fully use its features for oa desktop development. Does Libgdx have support for this?

Answer (score 4):

On the desktop, libGDX is built on top of [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/), which at of the time of this answer supports up to OpenGL version 4.5.

So if you're using libGDX on the desktop, then you can simply access the LWJGL calls directly. This will break your build for mobile or web deployment though.