# LibGdx should I use gl30?

Tags: java, libgdx

In configuration of libgdx, there is a useGL30 boolean. As I've never worked with OpenGL I'm not sure what that method does. And btw. should i set it to false or true? Which is better for my game?

Comment: The Android config or desktop config?

Comment: its for desktop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answer is very extensive but unfortunately not correct at some parts. First to answer your questions:

You want to set the `config.useGL30` member to `false`, regardless the platform (desktop or android).

You should *not* set the config.useGL30 member to `true`, unless you have an actual need to use OpenGL ES 3.0 functionality. In which case (if you need to use GLES3 functionality) you will need to take care of compatibility, even at places where you don't need that functionality.

Simply setting `config.useGL30` to `true` will *not* be better for your game. In fact, it might introduce issues.

To clarify a few things:

`OpenGL` and `OpenGL ES` are two different things, the versions can not be compared. If you really want to compare the versions, then OpenGL ES 2.0 can be compared with (is a subset of) OpenGL 4.3 and OpenGL ES 3.0 can be compared with (is a subset of) OpenGL 4.5.

In that respect the naming `useGL30`, `Gdx.gl20`, `Gdx.gl30` can be considered misleading, because the `20` and `30` in that naming is actually referring to the OpenGLES version and *not* the OpenGL version. A better naming would be perhaps `useGLES30`, `Gdx.gles20` and `Gdx.gles30`.

OpenGL ES 3.0 is *not* fully backwards compatible with OpenGL ES 2.0, which is also true for desktop (on which OpenGL ES is emulated through OpenGL). Even though the API itself is compatible, this isn't the case for the shader language used. So, if you set `config.useGL30` to `true` then chances are quite big that your shaders won't work anymore as you'd expect. This includes the shaders that come with libgdx (SpriteBatch, ShapeRenderer, ModelBatch, etc).

So, it doesn't make sense to set the `useGL30` member only to true for your desktop project, especially if you aren't making other adjustments to your code as well.

Comment: But, what are those changes in code that i have to add?

Comment: As said above, you would have to (at least) modify the shaders. The exact changes in your code depends on the usage as well as on other considerations (including the opengl context version you chose in your config if you target desktop). That would be a different question and not well suited for the comments section.

Comment: Can't confirm this for iOS, but [OpenGL ES 3 is backwards compatible with GLES 2 on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#manifest):`The OpenGL ES 3.x API is backwards-compatible with the 2.0 API, which means you can be more flexible with your implementation of OpenGL ES in your application`

Comment: You might want to read the answer again @Zoe: "Even though the API itself is compatible, this isn't the case for the shader language used."

Comment: So should you: `OpenGL ES 3.0 is *not* fully backwards compatible with OpenGL ES 2.0, which is also true for desktop`

Comment: You mean I should read what I wrote myself? That sentence is perfectly fine and correct. Please let's stop this nonsense, it doesn't add any value to the answer nor does it help the OP.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of [LwjglApplicationConfiguration](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration.html#useGL30):

> whether to attempt use OpenGL ES 3.0.

LibGDX uses a lot of features to maintain compatibility across multiple platforms. If you don't enable the setting, you can't use OpenGL 3 where it's possible (IIRC). Basically what the method does is enable the use of OpenGL ES 3. (I think all newer computers support OpenGL 3, the problem lies in Android where it was added in API 18 and it depends on custom implementations by manufacturers. I'll get back to that later)

It's worth checking out [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/147362/69046) even though the question is slightly different, it explains how LibGDX works:

> LibGDX is running OpenGL ES2.0, which is ancient by modern standards. It has to for compatibility reasons: Most mobile devices do not support any higher standard.
>
> OpenGL ES2.0 is similar to OpenGL 2.0, but with some changes, and was released in 2007. LWJGL, on the other hand, supports the latest and greatest (OpenGL 4.5) and everything below. It also has OpenCL (GPU processing), OpenAL (3D audio) and Vulkan (Magic drivers and stuff) bindings.

OpenGL ES 3 is the newest version available on Android (and I assume iOS devices as well), while OpenGL 4.6 is the newest available on desktop devices (where there is a graphics card that supports it).

One thing that's worth noting is that OpenGL ES 3 is also fairly old (2012) but it's backwards compatible with OpenGL ES 2.

Not knowing much about this particular part, this is more or less an educated guess: when you write code using LibGDX you make calls to `Gdx.gl` (or `Gdx.gl20` or `Gdx.gl30`). LibGDX then makes calls to the appropriate API (OpenGL ES on Android and iOS, LWJGL/JOGL on desktop, etc)

AFAIK, using `useGl30` enables the use of OpenGL ES 3. The main reason you shouldn't use OpenGL 3 is [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). OpenGL 3 is added in API 18, and:

> Caution: Support of the OpenGL ES 3.0 API on a device requires an implementation of this graphics pipeline provided by the device manufacturer. A device running Android 4.3 or higher may not support the OpenGL ES 3.0 API

But that isn't a problem for you since you (from what I understood) aren't targeting Android. So using the newest available is a good idea.

Meaning you could be using [Open GL 4.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_4.6). But this would mean [you would have to call the LWJGL bindings directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347153/libgdx-support-for-opengl-4).

The problem is that you can only do that for specific things, LibGDX itself will still use 2.0/3.0.

With all that in mind, I'm going to answer the two last questions:

> And btw. should i set it to false or true?

You should set it to `true` if you're not targeting Android. There will be problems as not all devices running API 18+ necessarily supports it (link to that is earlier in this answer). If you're running desktop you should target the newest one you can find, as the newer versions also add new features you may need. Unless there are specific things in OpenGL 4+ (4+ is not a typo) you should stick to the framework itself and not make calls directly to LWJGL (LibGDX on desktop is built on top of LWJGL).

You can make a game with OpenGL 2.0 alone. OpenGL 1 and 2 are not compatible, but 2 and 3 are. Meaning if you decide you want to use OpenGL 3, you can still make calls to OpenGL 2 (AFAIK, from experience with LWJGL, the later versions rely on each other to work properly. If you use 4 you still need to make calls to 2 and 3 to get the appropriate API's. I may be wrong on that though)

> Which is better for my game?

This is a matter of opinion, but there's one important thing you have to remember: If you use OpenGL 3, you can still use OpenGL 2. At that there's no choice between which you pick. If you enable OpenGL 3, you can use 2 and 3 [because openGL ES 3 is backwards compatible with OpenGL ES 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL_ES_3.0).

Something I haven't mentioned yet is using the different versions.

`Gdx.gl`, by default, uses OpenGL 2. Meaning if you want to access the 3.0 features, you have to call `Gdx.gl30.*` to the relevant methods. As it is backwards compatible, 2.0 features (I think) have to be called using `Gdx.gl20.*` as they aren't directly present in 3.0 (as a result of backwards compatibility, if you have 3.0 you also have 2.0)

<sub>I used LWJGL a while ago, and to call some of the fields that were added in earlier versions (but not removed) you had to call the relevant version. If you were using 4.6, you'd still need to call 2.0 to clear color. But this was a while ago, so I may remember incorrectly</sub>

So to sum up:

- You should use OpenGL 3 if you're on desktop only (because Android API 18+ may not support it. If you are targeting Android too, you have to consider whether or not you want to use OpenGL 3, and through that lose support for a lot of devices)
- `useGl30` enables the use of 3.0 where available.
- 2.0 and 3.0 are compatible, so you don't need to worry about which version you support. You can use both side by side.

Comment: So in libgdx project there is seperate runconfiguration for android and desktop which means in my desktop i'll enable it and in my android i'll disable it! Thanks for answer :)